Python: Iterating through 2 lists
I am trying to implement the following equation:

Where zc is an equally spaced range of values e.g.
t_array = np.arange(z_[0],z_[-1],0.01)
In this case
z_[0] = -15.336
z_[-1] = 15.336
I'm struggling to see what sort of while & for loop arrangement I would need so that it would iterate through the array of zc until the zc value reaches the z_ value, by which z_ should go to the next value in the array e.g. z_[i+1] and continue through zc.
Code snippet with relevant variables below
import numpy as np

z_ = np.array([-15.336,-14.5,-14,14,14.5,15.336])  #Distance from laminate midplane to laminate faces (zk)
nk = np.array([1,0.58,0.004126,0.58,1])          #Normalisation factor
b = np.array([300,300,300,300,300])             #width of laminate in mm

t_array = np.arange(z_[0],z_[-1],0.001)
t_array = np.append(t_array, z_[-1])
Itot = 146790.02
Qhat = np.zeros(len(t_array))

r = 0
# Iterate through t_array
for i, t in enumerate(t_array):
    # Calculate Qhat value based on the equation
    if r == 1 :
        Qhat[i] = b[r] * nk[r] / 2 * (t ** 2 - z_[r+1] ** 2)
    elif r == len(z_) - 1:
        Qhat[i] = b[r] * nk[r] / 2 * (t ** 2 - z_[r-1] ** 2)
    else:
        Qhat[i] = b[r] * nk[r] / 2 * (t ** 2 - z_[r-1] ** 2)
    
    # Move to the next index of z_ if t_array reaches the current value of z_
    if r < len(z_) - 1 and t >= z_[r + 1]:
        r += 1

Qhat = Qhat+Qhat_const
tau = -(9.81/Itot)*Qhat
plt.plot(tau,t_array)

This results in a mostly correct result. However it does not handle the first z_ correctly. I am expecting this type of plot:

It insetad generates this:

I am happy with the shape of the top half of the plot. I am seeing that it is not handling the first z_ value correctly and is shifting the values. The plot should start and end at 0 on the x axis.
I would also like this code to be functional for any number of layers. In all cases, len(b) = len(nk) and len(z_) = len(b+1)
EDIT: I have edited the code for some clarity

Is it correct that r starts at 1? you seem to skip the first values of b and nk (which have index 0). Also, multiple of your variables are either missing or unused which makes the code confusing to follow.

I have edited for clarity @JanWilamowski

you're still checking if r == 1 although that is probably supposed to be the first value (i.e. zero) and might explain the strange spike in your graph

if you're concerned about the first and last calculation results, try printing out all parts of that equation and validate if those make sense
